# How can I display text nodes in JavaScript before a prompt() in Safari?

Tags: javascript, text, safari, cross-browser

The code for a JavaScript-based game I'm working on uses appendChild() to add text elements to a content area, displaying information to the player. It then requests additional information from the player by popping up a prompt() dialog.

The simplest form of this is as follows:

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var tval = document.createElement("nstring");
tval.innerHTML = "Example text";
content.appendChild(tval);
prompt("Do you see the example text?","");
```

This works as expected when run under IE 8+, Chrome, and Firefox. The information text is displayed, then the prompt dialog is shown.

But under Safari, text elements added to the content area are not displayed until *after* the player has clicked "OK" or "Cancel" in the prompt dialog. (One distinction: in desktop Safari, the text is displayed after taking down the prompt; in mobile Safari, prompts are displayed, but the on-screen text is *never* displayed until the entire game ends.) This is making it impossible to play the game in either desktop or iPhone/iPad Safari browsers.

I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/5CQXU/7/ . Load the fiddle, click "OK" or "Cancel" on the initial prompt, then press the "Clear Screen" button in the Result pane of the fiddle.

When you Run the fiddle using IE, Chrome, and Firefox, all the "before" text lines are correctly shown in the Result pane prior to the prompt() dialog being displayed. And the "after" text line will only be displayed after you click on "OK" or "Cancel" to take down the prompt dialog.

Run the fiddle in Safari, however, and *none* of the text lines -- "before" or "after" -- will be displayed until after the prompt dialog is taken down, and then they are all displayed.

My working theory is that Safari, unlike IE, Chrome, and Firefox, is deferring screen writes until after some amount of time has passed following all I/O. So far, however, no amount of searching on SO or elsewhere has turned up any similar questions or answers.

I'm hoping someone can point me to an appropriate modification that will tell Safari (desktop and mobile) to immediately display text elements.

Comment: You can always put up the prompt after a short `setTimeout()` (allowing Safari to repaint the screen) or display your prompt in a non-modal way.

Comment: @jfriend00, I took a look at setTimeout(), but it doesn't seem to be compatible with using prompt(). I need the prompt to be displayed (to obtain user input) after some text is displayed, but before the rest of the processing. Putting the prompt() in a setTimeout() function would mean I have to find some other way of pausing output until the player has entered the requested information... but that's exactly what prompt() is supposed to do for me. I'm really hoping there's a flag or option that will tell Safari to process text immediately, but other constructive suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You can use `prompt()` after a short `setTimeout()` which will let the text display.  You just have to break your code into two pieces, one piece that is called before the `setTimeout()` and one piece that is called afterwards that puts up the `prompt()` and then does the rest.  It's a little code restructuring, but entirely doable.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vq363/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle example. I tried it (with a value of 50 ms) in my very reduced fiddle example, and it does work for desktop and mobile Safari. Unfortunately, applying this to my existing code would mean a significant amount of restructuring -- this project is a conversion to JavaScript of a PL/I game I last edited in 1985, and it's dependent on a prompt() function that pauses for user input without consuming all CPU (as a simple while() loop would do). What's frustrating is that my current solution works for every browser but Apple's.